# How do I print the triangle pattern below in C++?

Tags: c++

[image: Image of triangle output]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int rows, i, j, space;

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    for(i = rows; i >= 1; i--)
    {
       //for loop to put space
       for(space = i; space < rows; space++)
          cout << " ";
       //for loop for displaying star
       for(j = 1; j <= (1 * i ); j++)
          cout << "* ";

       cout << "\n";
    }


    for(i = 2; i <= rows; i++)
    {
       //for loop for displaying space
       for(space = i; space <= rows; space++)
       {
          cout << " ";
       }
       //for loop to display star equal to row number
       for(j = 1; j <= (1 * i ); j++)
       {
          cout << "*";
       }

       cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have used the code above and although the inverted pyramid above is correct, the pyramid below is not spaced properly..

Comment: Prefer using prefix increment (e.g. `++j`) to postfix (e.g. `j++`).

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 2; i <= rows; i++)
{
    for (space = i+1; space <= rows; space++)    //need to initialize space with i+1
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= (1 * i); j++)
    {
        cout << "* ";    //Need to add an extra space
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

This is the 2nd for loop, which has small modification.
Hope it solves you issue.